# Unable to set image on lock screen through GPO

Tags: group-policy

I am trying to apply a GPO for domain computers, to use a custom image on lock screen but without success.

Here is the GPO:

[image]
[image]

I always made `gpupdate \force` and also tried to reboot after and logout but no changes where made.

Here is the gpresult from a enduser machine:

[image]

Anyone knows what can be messing around?

Note: If you need more info just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that the file exists on the computers, the settings seems to be correct.

So, I think that you are not using Windows 10 Enterprise or Education? As stated in the Help text, you can only use this policy on Windows 10 Enterprise or Education, or Windows Server.

If your company uses Windows 10 Pro for example, this will not work.

However, if you are already using Win 10 Enterprise, then this may be another issue: try to manually edit the picture and save it again because Windows uses the last modified date/time of the file to detect if it should read the lock screen picture again

Comment: You are correct, I was not expecting that a Pro edition had such limitation. Can you please be more precise about that workaround? Thanks!

Comment: @marafado88 Sorry it was not a workaround. This policy is not available on Pro edition. I will edit my post to make that clearer because I wanted to say that "If you are using Windows 10 Enterprise **and** it's still not working then try to edit the picture to change the date/time"... but we are not in this use-case because you are using Win 10 Pro.